llc error "scope points into the type hierarchy"
I'm trying to use llvm/llc as a backend for my compiler, and I'm running into problems when I try to generate debug info for the code to make it debuggable.
Bascially, llc gives me a slew of errors:
!4 = !DILocation(line: 35, column: 8, scope: !5)
scope points into the type hierarchy
!25 = !DILocation(line: 38, column: 8, scope: !5)
scope points into the type hierarchy
!26 = !DILocation(line: 41, column: 8, scope: !5)
scope points into the type hierarchy
!27 = !DILocation(line: 30, column: 26, scope: !5)
scope points into the type hierarchy
warning: ignoring invalid debug info in foo.ll

It seems like it doesn't like the scope reference, but !5 is just the DISubProgram for the function:
!5 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "foo", linkageName: "foo", scope: !0, file: !1, line: 28, type: !6, spFlags: 0, retainedNodes: !24)

What could be going wrong here?  What does the error actually mean, as there is no type hierachy here at all -- just a compilation unit, a function, and some line numbers.
Here's a massively stripped down input that shows the problem:
; ModuleID = 'foo'
source_filename = "foo.src"

define i32 @foo() {
EntryBlock:
  ret i32 0, !dbg !4
}

!llvm.dbg.cu = !{!0}
!llvm.module.flags = !{!2, !3}

!0 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: 9999, file: !1, producer: "mycompiler", isOptimized: true, runtimeVersion: 1, emissionKind: FullDebug)
!1 = !DIFile(filename: "foo.src", directory: "")
!2 = !{i32 2, !"Dwarf Version", i32 3}
!3 = !{i32 1, !"Debug Info Version", i32 3}
!4 = !DILocation(line: 35, column: 8, scope: !5)
!5 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "foo", linkageName: "foo", scope: !0, file: !1, line: 28, type: !6, spFlags: 0, retainedNodes: !9)
!6 = !DISubroutineType(types: !7) 
!7 = !{!8}
!8 = !DIBasicType(name: "u32", size: 32, encoding: DW_ATE_unsigned)
!9 = !{}

